# In Tableau - how to Count first instance as 1 and following instance as 2

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I have a table in Tableau where there's a column with some alpha-numeric values (Concatenated Key column) and these are repeating in the below rows. I want to count the first instance as 1 and others as 2. Can someone help here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWdGt.png)

Comment: Table calcs are the only calculations in Tableau proper that can take row order into account, but might be more tricky than you’d like for this purpose. I’d first try to do this in preprocessing the data - say with Python — or using an  analytic custom sql query